# Can i call model.fit multiple times in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a long dataset and i need to train it in chunks. I have read that it is possible to call model.fit multiple times but it would be better to use model.train_on_batch. That is true? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using model.fit multiple. You can use make_csv_dataset function in tensorflow and pass the dataset to your fit command.
Assuming your data is in csv format. The advantage of this fucntion is that it loads the data as and when required instead of loading everything in your main memory.

```
tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern, 
    batch_size,
    label_name=None, 
    select_columns=None, 
    shuffle=True,
)
```

Here file pattern is single string ie. name of file or string pattern if you want to load multiple files. See [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset)

If you have image dataset you can use something called as flow_from_directory. This works in similar fashion. It loads only the images required for processing.

```
# this is preprocessing step where you define preprocessing on images.
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# this is where you create iterator.
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

See [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)